Can I run a program under windows in a compatibility mode using pcalua.exe?
It is not "officially" documented but looks like pcalua.exe is the command line interface for the program compatibility assistant on Windows. Also not officially documented but you can start a program using the following switches -a for the application to be ran (you can use also the full path to it), -c for the arguments passed to the application (better to be the last one in order to not attach arguments passed to pcalua to the called program), -d for the directory where the application will be started. I'm not aware of any other switches. Example command:
pcalua -a msg.exe -d "%windir%" -c * /w test-message

Interestingly an application can be started even with program compatibility service shut down. My assumption was that the __COMPAT_LAYER settings will be taken into account but seems they are ignored.
So how can I start a program/application/script/.. using pcalua in a compatibility mode (e.g. 640x480 because it will be easy for verification)? Is it possible?
